# decimales de c# a sql server

Tags: c#, sql, windows, servidor

reformule mi pregunta que sea mas exacto,
intento insertar un decimal de  c# a sql server.

este es le evento click del button guardar mas la conexion pero no lo realiza

```
private void btnBunifuGuardarCargoDirecto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {

try



 {




SqlConnection Conn = BDComun.ObtenerConexion();

     SqlCommand consulta = new SqlCommand("insert into cargoDirecto(costoUnitario) values(@costoUnitario)", Conn);

                consulta.Parameters.AddWithValue(",@costoUnitario", Convert.ToDecimal(txtCostoUnitarioCargoDirecto.Text.Replace(",",".")));
                consulta.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex);
            }
        }
```

no me conecta con la bd y no inserta, nose que pueda ser,
gracias por su tiempo y ayuda amigos!

Comment: Porfavor aclara un poco tu pregunta, cuál es el problema? no se inserta? dispara alguna excepción?  ¿qué pasa?

Comment: no se inserta,txtCantidad.text, txtCostoUnitario.text, txtCostoTotal.text

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(",@costoUnitario"` tienes una coma antes de la `@`, debes quitarla. Lo mismo en `,@@costoTotalCargoDirecto`, debe ser `@costoTotalCargoDirecto`.

Comment: **encontre la respuesta**, lo mejor fue guardar todo como string y despues crear una consulta de c# cambiando el string a decimal y hay poder multiplicar, quizas es un poco mas de pega, pero es lo mas rapido y legible

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que tienes que respetar el tipo de dato de cada parametros, entonces debes usar

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", dateTimePickerFechaCargoDirecto.Value);
```

si usas un `DateTimePicker` este devuelve un `DateTime` con la propiedad `Value`

Si vas a definir un valor numerico tambien debes respectarlo

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@costoUnitario", Convert.ToDecimal(txtCostoUnitarioCargoDirecto.Text));

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidadCargoDirecto.Text));
```

ya sea `decimal` o `int` debes convertir el `string` a estos tipos de datos

Comment: un detalle, ojo que en los parametros "@costoUnitario" y "@costoTotalCargoDirecto" estas poniendo una coma en el nombre, eso deberias quitarlo

Comment: cambie los datos que me observas

Comment: vi el codigo que publicaste, no tienes que poner ningun Replace() en el AddWithValue() solo quita la coma del nombre del parametro, solo deja "@costoUnitario"

Answer (score 0):

Primero veo que tienes 2 parametros con el nombre mal escrito ya que incluyes ","

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(",@costoUnitario", txtCostoUnitarioCargoDirecto.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(",@@costoTotalCargoDirecto", txtCostoTotalCargoDirecto.Text);
```

Adicional a esto si quieres guardar decimales en la base de datos debes validar la `COLLATION` de ella, por ejemplo si es `Modern_Spanish_CI_AI` usaras "`,`" para separar decimales (a pesar de que al abrir el SSMS se vea como puntos) por lo que el valor que recuperas del `TextBox` deberás utilizar una máscara para que solo reciba "`,`" o bien puedes antes de guardar el valor en la base de datos utilizar un REPLACE en el textbox  ( `REPLACE(txtCostoTotalCargoDirecto.Text,".",","`) .

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: cambie los datos que me observas